# Pinterest-like plugin with dynamic block height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I want to make a page of Pinterest-like style and each block may change height and I want them rearranged only in its column.

For example, when page is loaded, the layout may be:

```
------------------------------------
|         |                |       |
|         |                |       |
|---------|                |       |
|Hello! I |                |       |
|am Alice.|----------------|       |
|---------|                |       |
|WoW!     |                |       |
```

If user click on one block, it changes in height and ideally it should be like:

```
------------------------------------
|         |                |       |
|         |                |       |
|---------|                |       |
|Hello! I |                |       |
|am Alice.|----------------|       |
|Who are  |                |       |
|you?     |                |       |
|---------|                |       |
|WoW!     |                |       |
```

I've tried with [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html) and [ShapeShift](http://mcpants.github.io/jquery.shapeshift/), both of them act similarly. By default, the position of all blocks will not change when the height of some blocks changes. So `Who are you?` will be under `WoW!` and it still looks like:

```
------------------------------------
|         |                |       |
|         |                |       |
|---------|                |       |
|Hello! I |                |       |
|am Alice.|----------------|       |
|---------|                |       |
|WoW!     |                |       |
```

I can manually call a function to rearrange them (e.g.: `$('.container').trigger("ss-rearrange");` for ShapeShift), but blocks may be arranged to a different column, which is not ideal.

I want to know if there's a library or how should I achieve this? I need the blocks moves only in its current column when height changes.

Comment: @JasonSperske I said I've tried with it, but it will not rearrange correctly when height of a block changes.

Comment: My mistake, sorry I missed that part

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** Have a look at masonry's documentation:

```
var container = document.querySelector('#layout-demo .masonry');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  columnWidth: 60
});

eventie.bind( container, 'click', function( event ) {
  // don't proceed if item was not clicked on
  if ( !classie.has( event.target, 'item' ) ) {
    return;
  }
  // change size of item via class
  classie.toggle( event.target, 'gigante' );
  // trigger layout
  msnry.layout();
});
```

**msnry.layout()** is what you want to do.

Source: http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html

See codepen: http://codepen.io/johannesjo/pen/kFixz

**(2)** You can also try using **css-columns**: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/03/how-to-use-css3-columns/

**(3)** If you don't want to change columns like with masonry or css-columns, you should be able to use simple **floating containers**.  You would have to sort the content by yourself though. In your case, it might be the best solution, as all other methods are expected to reevaluate the position of the elements based on their size.

**(4)** If you don't mind overlapping elements, you can use masonry cells with toggling a hidden div inside (with display: none). Without calling layout() the element will maintain its position like you described in your question.

Comment: No, this is not I want. `layout()` will change blocks into different columns than they were in before.

Comment: Not in the example, but if the width is the same and there is enough space it doesn't change the column:
http://codepen.io/johannesjo/pen/kFixz

Comment: I don't want any item to change columns. But in this example, only the clicked item didn't change column.

Comment: If you don’t want to changes any column use (2) floats or remove masonry after applying it once.

Comment: I don't want to use css-columns since it's still young and not all browsers support that. And I do mind overlapping elements... Seems quite hard to achieve this. I guess I have to choose (3) if there aren't any better solution. Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to use css-columns and have a float fall-back using modernizr, but I fear that css columns will reevaluate the position of the elments as well.